# JSP Invoke Fragment with parameters

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Can you declare parameters in JSP fragments ?

Something like:

```
<ns:myTag>
    <jsp:attribute name="myFrag">
        <jsp:attribute name="fragmentParameter" /> 
        Can access parameter with ${fragmentParameter}
    </jsp:attribute>
</ns:myTag>
```

We don't want nested jsp:attributes, but that's just to get the idea.

Then the fragment could be invoked inside the tag myTag:

```
<jsp:invoke fragment="myFrag">
     <jsp:attribute var="fragmentParameter" value="ParamX" />
</jsp:invoke>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes... kind of.

In the tag, set `someVar` value as a `tagVar` request scoped variable:

```
<c:set var="tagVar" value="${someVar}" scope="request" />
<jsp:doBody />
```

In this way you can invoke the tag fragment (or body) making the tag provided `tagVar` variable available to the tag caller:

```
<t:myTag>
  Doing something useful with ${tagVar}
</t:myTag>
```